# Mysql full text search dont work when i search a word with &

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Mysql Match doesn't work when I search a word like -> T&T because of the &

what can I make?

```
SELECT * FROM marke 
WHERE MATCH(brand) 
      AGAINST ('T&T' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

or what alternatives to MATCH can I use?

sorry for my English

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: Returns 0 results